# avoiding JBPM logs from printing on jboss server

Tags: jbpm

I m using `jbpm4.3` and `jboss` as an application server. When I deploy my application on jboss server, it prints the logs like

```
"FINE: updating variable 'GoalId' in 'execution[GoalProcess.10001]' to value 'GoalProcess.10001'
10:55:26,428 ERROR [STDERR] 12 Dec, 2010 10:55:26 AM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log debug
FINE: updating variable 'status_1' in 'execution[GoalProcess.10001]' to value 'OPEN'
10:55:26,429 ERROR [STDERR] 12 Dec, 2010 10:55:26 AM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log debug
"

Note:" all type of FINE, FINEST logs"
```

so, is there any way to avoid it from printing on jboss server.If so, please r'ply me as soon as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

JDK logger by default logs to standard error. And JBoss translates all standard error stream messages as log4j errors. That's why you see that mess.

Now try to use a different logging framework:
http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbpm/jbpm4/trunk/log/src/main/java/org/jbpm/internal/log/

I don't have a jbpm 4 at hand, so can't give you an exact answer. But you should have some logging service defined in jbpm.cfg.xml. Probably something like:

```
 <service name="logging" factory="org.jbpm.logging.db.Jdk14LogFactory" />
```